# Doctrine add existing foreign keys when schema is updated (mysql)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following entities:

> A.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="a")
 * @ORM\Entity() 
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * One Cart has One Customer.
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="a")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $b;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="C", inversedBy="a")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="c_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $c;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="D", inversedBy="a")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="d_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $d;
}
```

> B.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="b")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class B
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="b")
     */
    private $a;
}
```

> C.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="c")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class C
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="c")
     */
    private $a;
}
```

> D.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="d")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class D
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="d")
     */
    private $a;
}
```

I executing commands:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Last command prints:

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD CONSTRAINT FK_E8B7BE43296BFCB6 FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b (id);
```

But this constraint is added before, so I can't to use

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Two times without error.

This behavior occurs only when I am using MySQL. When I removed MySQL and installed MariaDB problem vanished.

Should I introduce changes in my entities, or is it bug of Doctrine?

Comment: Try with postgresql

Comment: With Postgresql this exemplary code works correctly. Problem is only for MySQL.

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting ?

Comment: Exception telling that constraint already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug. Try using DoctrineMigrations bundle so that you can control migration classes before applying them.

Comment: Finally I changed MySQL to MariaDB. Of course there is workaround - usage simple script with grep, but migration to MariaDB was simpler.